# Blender Subdivision mod doesn't work more than 1 level

Tags: mesh, modifiers, subdivision-surface

- Blender Subdivision mod doesn't work more than 1 level.
- This is the first time I have had this problem in my current working file (other files are fine) so I think I clicked something stupid.
- File here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GY1MQimn1CcDDLGrqtQ2khOii6Khh770/view?usp=sharing

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've activated the *Simplify* option in the *Render* panel, disable it or increase the *Max Subdivision* value:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, It worked.